# How to remove an empty map from YAML using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I need to remove an empty map from a YAML, using [YQ](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)
Sometimes this map may have values, and sometimes this will appears empty.

My YAML code looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  annotations: {}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-03-24T13:16:10Z"
```

I need to remove `annotations: {}`

My desired output:

```yaml
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-03-24T13:16:10Z"
```

Anybody can helps me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the `annotations` map when its length is 0. Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), this can be done as below (verfied on yq version 4.9.6)

```bash
yq e 'del(.metadata.annotations | select(length==0))' yaml
```

Note: Since [4.18.1](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1), yq's `eval/e` command is the default command and no longer needs to be specified.

Answer (score 5):

#### [mikefarah/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)

For a generic approach you can use the command

`yq e 'del(.. | select(tag == "!!map" and length == 0))'`

to remove all empty objects in the input.

Change `!!map` with `!!seq` if you want to do the same for empty arrays.

---

#### [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)

Remove empty objects: `yq -y 'del(.. | select(objects and length == 0))'`

Remove empty arrays: `yq -y 'del(.. | select(arrays and length == 0))'`

Remove empty objects, arrays and strings: `yq -y 'del(.. | select(length == 0))'`

Answer (score 0):

From the [@jpseng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16332641/jpseng)'s anwser, I get the command only removes empty objects at the leaf nodes, since it may create more empty objects, like key `a` or `d`(and `d` eventually):

```bash
$ cat example.yaml
a:
  b: {}
c:
  d:
    e: {}
f: "exists"

$ yq 'del(.. | select(tag=="!!map" and length == 0))' example.yaml
a: {}
c:
  d: {}
f: "exists"
```

Remove these recursively by Bash script

```bash
$ cat delete_empty_map.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

result=$(yq 'del( .. | select(tag == "!!map" and length == 0))' "$1")
while [ "$(echo "$result" | yq 'map(.. | select(tag == "!!map" and length == 0)) | any')" = "true" ]
do
  result=$(echo "$result" | yq 'del( .. | select(tag == "!!map" and length == 0))')
done

echo "$result" | yq

$ ./delete_empty_map.sh example.yaml
f: "exists"
```