How to remove empty yaml properties?
I need to remove all properties of yaml in markdown files that have empty values recursively in a directory.
Before:
---
aliases:
cssclasses:
  - rss
tags: 
---

After:
---
cssclasses:
  - rss
---

It should remove the entire line no matter what object type it is: array, map, etc.
I'd like to do this with mikefarah/yq. I currently tried, based another question to run the following:
yq -i 'del(.. | select(tag == "!!seq" and length == 0))' Hello.md and also replacing !!seq with !!map
$ yq -i 'del(.. | select(tag == "!!map" and length == 0))' Hello.md
---
aliases:
cssclasses:
  - rss
tags:
---

However, the command did not anything.
I also tried the first answer to this question (yq 'del(.. | select(. == ~))' Hello.md), but the command ends up eating up the bottom --- at all times which removes denotation of YAML e.g.
---
aliases:
cssclasses:
  - rss
tags:



The aliases and tags fields from your sample actually hold null values. Thus, select them by checking the context . for equality to null (or ~):
yq 'del(.. | select(. == null))' Hello.md
# or
yq 'del(.. | select(. == ~))' Hello.md  # mikefarah/yq only

Note that ~ isn't recognized by kislyuk/yq, and that in mikefarah/yq since version 4.18.1, the eval (or e) command is the default command, and can be omitted.

Now that this works for individual files, then how can I recursively run it for all markdown files in the working directory?

The -i flag can only "update the file in place of first file given", so you'll need to script it in the environment you're calling yq from. Check out xargs if this is an option.

For some reason, the command also removes the bottom --- line, which denotes that part of the markdown is YAML. I tested this for many scenarios. Has this not happened for you?

I could not get this command to work without removing the --- line at the bottom, and other solutions (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68291270/21007693) have not worked. Please help change the solution, as I don't want to duplicate the post.
